# Pagination on set of records of varying order using ajax - RoR

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

It is bit difficult to explain, but I'm facing problem in pagination of set of records. The problem is becoming complex because the sorting order of records changes. Let me explain it with some example for better idea.

There are "posts". Posts has many comments. I'm sorting the posts as, post on with latest comment will be shown on the top.

For ex. if there are 4 posts and the initial order is B, D, A, C. And I'm showing one post at a time. When user click "more" link next post will show.

So the sequence will be:
"B" -> click "more" -> "D" -> click "more" -> "A" (B -> D -> A)

But in other case if any comment added on post before it is displayed, it will give wrong result.

Again considering the example above. Initial order is B, D, A, C

"B" -> click "more" -> "D" (B -> D)

now some comment added on "A", so the new order will be A, B, D, C
so now when I click on "more"  I get "D" i.e. o/p >> B -> D -> D -> C

Any insights, on this issue are highly appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue with use of timestamp. The timestamp is noted when page is requested for first time. And if any activity that happens after that timestamp is ignored. So I get the same sequence.